# Adding additional class with ng-class

Tags: html, angularjs

I used yeoman angular generator to scaffold my app, and now I'm working on a specific view.

I'm building a simple `ng-repeat` function, in order to clean up my html and avoid repeating the same markup 4 times.

I am making content panels, and want to add a class specific to the content, so I can style it with Sass. I tried using `ng-class` but so far I've been unable to make it work.

I am new to AngularJS, I tried reading the [official ng-class documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [this writeup](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) but so far I'm unable to make it work. I guess it just takes a while to get used to Angular.

here's my view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="LandingController">
    <div ng-repeat="panel in panels">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            {{ panel.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content" ng-class="{{panel.contentClass}}" data-ng-bind-html="panel.content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
    .controller('LandingController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.panels = [
            {
                title: 'lokacija',
                contentClass: 'location',
                content:'<p>Institut Jožef Stefan<br>Jamova 30<br>1000 Ljubljana</p><br><div class="map-container"></div>'
            },
            {
                title: 'kontakt',
                contentClass: 'location',
                content: ''
            },
            {
                title: 'delovni čas',
                contentClass: 'location',
                content: ''
            },
            {
                title: 'katalog',
                contentClass: 'location',
                content: ''
            }
        ];
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) operates in three different ways, depending on which of three types the expression evaluates to:

1. If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names. (*this will match with your case*)
2. If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.*(EX: '`ng-class="{'my-class': (true/false expression)}"`)*
3. If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array should either be a string as in type 1 or an object as in type 2. This means that you can mix strings and objects together in an array to give you more control over what CSS classes appear. See the code below for an example of this. *`(EX: ng-class="[style1, style2, style3]")` refer ng-class doc and you will get more info.*

so you can directly use `ng-class="panel.contentClass"` this will match with the first list item witch is `If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names.`.

you can simply change `ng-class="{{panel.contentClass}}"` to `ng-class="panel.contentClass"` because `ng-class` accepts a `expression` not a interpolated value.

```
<div class="panel-content" ng-class="panel.contentClass" data-ng-bind-html="panel.content">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2pmjRGrjHL2roesFpS0?p=preview)

Comment: For some reason the inspector shows it as ng-class instead of the regular class. This was the first thing I tried, but apparently I nested some of my css wrong, and it didn't work

Comment: regular class will add to the `class` :)

Comment: rechecked, nesting was right but still won't work. If I target the new class directly it works, but if I nest it under .panel content like this `.panel-content .location {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}` it brakes. Any idea why?

Comment: ah this is the issue `ng-class` is applied to the `div` and that div also have `panel-content` class, so both classes add to the same element, so you need to change your css to match it as, `.panel-content.location {...}` no spaces between `.panel-content` and `.location`. I think you know the differences with and without spaces between `.panel-content` and `.location`.

Comment: try this, `.panel-content { &.location {text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;}  }`

Answer (score 1):

You are using ng-class in wrong way. ng-class is use to add/remove class conditionally and dynamically.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) is full documentation of ng-class.

ng-class requires json in which key is class name and value is condition. if value satisfies, it add that class else not.

for Ex.

```
<div class="panel-content" ng-class="{'my-class':panel.contentClass}" data-ng-bind-html="panel.content">
```

it adds my-class if value of panel.contentClass is true.

if you are taking class name from panel.contentClass then better way to use class attribute only instead of ng-class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089350/using-class-with-angular-vs-ng-class-while-using-a-mixed-expression) is reference.

For ex.

```
<div class="panel-content, {{panel.contentClass}}" data-ng-bind-html="panel.content">
```

Comment: I suppose if you will not provide any conditions, it will apply that class on that element, permanentely

Comment: what do you mean if you not provide any condition? this is simply same as using class attribute.

Comment: @Vineet, I updated my answer, I hope you got what you are looking for.

Comment: The second part of your anwser is what I was looking for, without the separator in the class definition (,). Thanks for writing it up in a way that's easy to understand, and explaining why ng-class is not the corret choice